# Doctests fail with UnicodeDecodeError on C-extension and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest, python-c-extension

I am having difficulty getting my testing framework to work for a C-extension module for both Python2 and Python3. I like to run my docstrings through `doctest` to make sure that I am not feeding my users bad information, so I want to run `doctest` as part of my testing.

I don't believe that the source of my problem is the docstrings themselves, but rather how the `doctest` module is trying to read my extension module.  If I run `doctest` with Python2 (on the module compiled against Python2), I get the output that I expect:

```
$ python -m doctest myext.so -v
...
1 items passed all tests:
98 tests in myext.so
98 tests in 1 items.
98 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

However, when I do the same but with Python3, I get a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
$ python3 -m doctest myext3.so -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/doctest.py", line 223, in _load_testfile
    return f.read(), filename
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/codecs.py", line 301, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

To get some more info, I ran it through `pytest` with full traceback:

```
$ python3 -m pytest --doctest-glob "*.so" --full-trace
...
self = <encodings.utf_8.IncrementalDecoder object at 0x102ff5110>
input = b'\xcf\xfa\xed\xfe\x07\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x05\x00\x00\x85\x00\x00\x00\x00\x...edString\x00_PyUnicode_FromString\x00_Py_BuildValue\x00__Py_FalseStruct\x00__Py_TrueStruct\x00dyld_stub_binder\x00\x00'
final = True

    def decode(self, input, final=False):
        # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
        data = self.buffer + input
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
E       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/codecs.py:301: UnicodeDecodeError
```

---

It looks like `doctest` is actually *reading* the `.so` file to get the docstrings (rather than importing the module), but Python3 doesn't know how to decode the input.  I can confirm this by replicating the byte string and traceback by trying to read the `.so` file myself:

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.3 (default, Dec 10 2013, 20:13:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open('myext3.so').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/codecs.py", line 301, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>>> open('myext3.so', 'rb').read()
b'\xcf\xfa\xed\xfe\x07\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x05...'
```

---

Has anyone else run into this problem before?  Is there a standard (or not-so-standard) way to get `doctest` to execute tests on C extension modules on python3?

**Update**: I should also add that I get identical results on Travis-CI ([see here](https://travis-ci.org/SethMMorton/fastnumbers/jobs/31680811)), so it's not specific to my local build.

Comment: Perhaps there's a different version of `doctest` you need to compile for Python 3?

Comment: For python3, I am using the doctest module from the std lib. Is there another version you recommend?  Isn't doctest a pure python module, so does it need compilation?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used `doctest` before, didn't realize it was a built in module. Maybe your PYTHONPATH is putting the version 2 module ahead of the version 3 one?

Comment: My PYTHONPATH is empty... I rely solely on the hardcoded paths in `sys.path`.  Also, in the first traceback you can see that the `doctest.py` file is in the python 3.3 standard library location, so I don't think that is the problem.  I appreciate your suggestions, keep them coming!

Answer (score 3):

I have found a workaround to this problem so I will post it, but I find it rather unsatisfying.  I am still looking for more elegant/less hacky solutions to this.

---

There are **three** problems with `doctest.py` that need to be overcome to make this work:

**1) Get doctest to consider .so files as python modules.**

If you look at the `doctest.py` source, you will notice in the test runner a block that looks similar to this (depending on the python version you are running):

```
if filename.endswith(".py"):
    # It is a module -- insert its dir into sys.path and try to
    # import it. If it is part of a package, that possibly
    # won't work because of package imports.
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(filename)
    sys.path.insert(0, dirname)
    m = __import__(filename[:-3])
    del sys.path[0]
    failures, _ = testmod(m)
else:
    failures, _ = testfile(filename, module_relative=False)
```

What is happening here is `doctest.py` is checking for the ".py" extension, and if so the file is loaded as a python module, but otherwise the file is read as if it were text (like a README.rst might be).  We need to get `doctest.py` to acknowledge that a file with ".so" extension is a python module.  To do this, simply add a check for the ".so" extension by modifying this `if` block to read

```
if filename.endswith(".py") or filename.endswith(".so"):
    ...
```

**2) Get doctest to identify the functions in the C-extension module**

`doctest.py` uses the [inspect.isfunction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) function to determine what objects are functions when recursively searching for docstrings within a module object.  The problem with this function is that it only identifies functions written in python, not in C (python identifies C-extension functions as builtin).  So, to identify our functions when recursing through the module, we need to use [inspect.isbuiltin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isbuiltin) instead.

To rectify this, we need to locate the `DocTestFinder._find` method in `doctest.py` and change how it looks for functions.  I converted

```
# Recurse to functions & classes.
if ((inspect.isfunction(val) or inspect.isclass(val)) and
    self._from_module(module, val)):
    self._find(tests, val, valname, module, source_lines,
               globs, seen)
```

to

```
# Recurse to functions & classes.
if ((inspect.isbuiltin(val) or inspect.isclass(val)) and
    self._from_module(module, val)):
    self._find(tests, val, valname, module, source_lines,
               globs, seen)
```

**3) Properly remove the version tag on the .so file (Python3 only).**

On Python3, C-extensions can be tagged with a version identifier (i.e. "myext.cpython-3mu.so", please see [PEP 3149](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/)).  We need to know how to remove this when doing the initial import in the `doctest.py` test runner.

To do this, I converted the line

```
m = __import__(filename[:-3])
```

to

```
from sysconfig import get_config_var
m = __import__(filename[:-3] if filename.endswith(".py") else filename.replace(get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX"), ""))
```

This is only needed for Python3.

---

After making these modifications, I can get doctest to work as expected on both Python2 and Python3.  Since these modifications are rather annoying, I have made a `patch_doctest.py` script that does this automatically and puts the patched `doctest.py` in your current directory.  You can get this file [here](https://github.com/SethMMorton/fastnumbers/blob/develop/patch_doctest.py) if you want to use it.  You can then run the tests on the extension modules like this

```
$ python2 patch_doctest.py
$ python2 -m doctest myext2.so
$ rm doctest.py
$ python3 patch_doctest.py
$ python3 -m doctest myext3.so
```

As evidence that this works, [here are the new Travis-CI results](https://travis-ci.org/SethMMorton/fastnumbers/builds/31772265).

Comment: Considering that it doesn't take *much* to get this to work, I wonder if this is an enhancement the python devs might be interested in...